# Xamarin.Forms: Add padding to label in grid?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

A grid cell looks like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
       Grid.Row="0" 
       Grid.Column="1" 
       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
       FontSize="16" 
       TextColor="White" 
       BackgroundColor="red" />
```

There are 2 columns, and each column is 50% of the width. With the xaml above, the whole cell (half the row) will be painted red.

It looks like this:

[image]

Can I add left and/or right padding just to `Grid.Row="0"` and  `Grid.Column="1"` so that the column is still 50% width but not the label? What I don't want to do is change the grid structure (ie. add more columns).

The desired result is something like this, but without having to add more columns or change column size:

[image]

Comment: just add Padding or Margin values to the Label?  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: I've edited the question to show what I would like the result to look like.

Comment: I guess it's like the `padding-left` and `padding-right` properties in CSS.

Comment: You can try by applying HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" in that label so that it will expand only as much as text inside it, or else give fix width to that label if you want only that much space and apply LineBreakMode.

Comment: Hey ,did you solve the issue?

Comment: I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `HorizontalOptions="Center"` if you just want to place in the middle of the column. In this method, if the label's text is increased, the space around the label decreases.

If you want to have a certain amount of space around the label, you should set `Margin` for Label.

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
       Grid.Row="0" 
       Grid.Column="1" 
       Margin="20,0"
       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
       FontSize="16" 
       TextColor="White" 
       BackgroundColor="red" />
```

Comment: Can you add example of how you would use `Margin` for label?

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the label in a `StackLayout` and set the padding of it.Such as:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Padding="10,0,10,0">
  <Label  
        Text="text"  
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
        FontSize="16" 
        TextColor="White" 
        BackgroundColor="red" />
</StackLayout>
```

PS:Differernt from padding in CSS (top-right-buttom-left),the order of the padding in xamarin is left-top-right-buttom.

For more detail you can refer [Margin and Padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood that correctly you need margin and not padding. For the very same reason, you won't find a padding property in Label, like many other views in Xamarin Forms.

This should serve your purpose.

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
       Grid.Row="0" 
       Grid.Column="1"
       Margin="20, 0, 20, 0" 
       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
       FontSize="16" 
       TextColor="White" 
       BackgroundColor="red" />
```

To understand how padding and margin works in details, you can check this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding